# QWebView does not reload .css file

Tags: css, qt, qwebview

I show a local .html file which references to a local .css file on a QWebView. When I change the .html file and reload the file in the QWebView, the changes are visible. But when I change the .css file, the changes are not adopted. Even when I create a completely new QWebView, where is still the old stylesheet. I have to restart the whole program, to make changes visible, which is no option because I edit the .css file in the program.

Is there a way to make the QWebView to reload the stylesheet file?

Comment: Did you try `QWebView::reload`?

Comment: QWebView::reload was the first thing I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `webView->page()->settings()->clearMemoryCaches();` before reload